# Why do I randomly have no disk in "Other Locations" of nautilus on some boot?

Tags: boot, mount, nautilus

I have several physical data disks on my computer, and they usually show up in the "Other Locations" pannel of Nautilus:

[image: Normal display of Other Locations]

But sometimes, on some boot, and without any apparent reason, I might have no disk here. Instead, I see, on the left pannel, the uid of the physical disk where the system is (c690e...), a floppy0 support (I have no floppy drive), and the two partitions of that physical system disk ("perso", which is mounted usually automatically on /mnt/perso/ and the "Racine du système", which is the "system root")

[image: Buggy behavior]

And in the taskbar, I don't have the "SSD" icon I usually have, but instead, I get two icons that look kind of like "CD drives" corresponding to the "perso" and "racine du système" partitions

[image: taskbar]

Do you have any idea why this behavior occur, and how I can avoid that? or maybe, at least, fix that without rebooting the system?

`uname -rms` returns `Linux 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64`

`lsb_release -a` returns `No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Release:   20.04 Codename: focal`

Tell me (the commands) if you need more infos

Comment: Does [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-properly-automount-a-drive-in-ubuntu-linux/) help you?